# iOS Search bar closes when letter pressed

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I have this weird issue with the searchbar in swift 3.

So I would like the Search Bar to be sticked to the top of a table view (without putting it in storyboard though)
and i have the following code.

```
    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()



            searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
            searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
            definesPresentationContext = true
            searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search for Event Name or Category"
    }


        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
            return self.searchController.searchBar
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
            return searchController.searchBar.frame.height
        }
```

So when i scroll up and down the table view it is true that the search bar remains on top.
When i press the search bar to enter a text, it shows me the keyboard and the Cancel Button.

If i press the cancel button, the keyboard dissapears, which is normal.

But if i press something from the keyboard (lets say the letter `A`)
it filters the table view and closes the keyboard. It also doesnt let me press cancel or the (x) button.
Any idea why?

P.S. In simulator is working great ! But in my iPhone SE is doing the above!

Comment: Why dont you add searchbar as UITableviewHeader?

Comment: @Dev_Tandel because it will not be sticked at the top of the tableview when i scroll down

Answer (score 1):

Erase your two functions for header and add these lines inside the viewDidLoad above your lines.

```
 searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
        let tableHeaderView: UIView = UIView.init(frame: searchController.searchBar.frame)
        tableHeaderView.addSubview(searchController.searchBar)
        self.locationTable.tableHeaderView = tableHeaderView
```

And then put this function too:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        let searchBar:UISearchBar = searchController.searchBar
        var searchBarFrame:CGRect = searchBar.frame
        if searchController.isActive {

            searchBarFrame.origin.y = 0
        }
        else {
            searchBarFrame.origin.y = max(0, scrollView.contentOffset.y + scrollView.contentInset.top)

        }
        searchController.searchBar.frame = searchBarFrame
    }
```

Now I believe you will have the result you wanted.

Hope it helps